# Two tables, with indexes, with the same column names, containing different info... will there be a conflict?

Tags: mysql, indexing, myisam, webmin

So I have a class that creates a table to be populated with data. Right now I have all the column names the same (product_name, date, etc). I noticed that when I view my tables in Webmin that there is only one index named "product_date" despite the fact that there are, supposedly, two tables using the index. I don't think this can be good.

My question is whether or not this will cause a conflict in the future? I don't want to populate the tables with thousands of rows if I'm only going to need to restructure everything later. I can't imagine that I'm the first to encounter this... maybe I'm just misinformed on how indexes work/webmin displays indexes and being overly paranoid.

(edit)

In response to one comment below, here are the results of SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename:

```
 c_1    | CREATE TABLE c_1 (
  p_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  nm varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  m_name text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (p_id),
  KEY nm (nm),
  FULLTEXT KEY m_name (m_name)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

 c_2    | CREATE TABLE c_2 (
  p_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  ne varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  m_name text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (p_id),
  KEY nm (nm),
  FULLTEXT KEY metaphone_name (m_name)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Note that all the indexes on equivalent columns are named the same way.

Comment: Are you checking the index on both table or on a single table? Maybe indexes are created on both tables. Try `show create table yourtablename` on both tables to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an index per table, no problem

Comment: I think you're right, my problem was my unfamiliarity with Webmin which makes it look like there is only a single per column index shared by multiple tables. That's what I get for using a GUI. I was able to use `SHOW INDEXES FROM c1;` and `SHOW INDEXES FROM c2;` and they both looked legit... thanks for the help.

Comment: Will "DROP INDEX index_name" drop index_name from all table containing a index named index_name? @Brian

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly (a big if), you must create an index for *each* table. Indexes do not cover more than one table until you get into advanced concepts like indexed/materialized views, which I don't think MySQL handles.

Comment: When I create the tables, I am creating an index for each table... but my indexes have the same names. I need to know if that will create a conflict later, or if I should change the column names on each table so that the indexes (that are being automatically created upon table creation) are named differently.